# Placing corresponding boxes side by side in boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

I have durations for words in speaking turns. I want to compare durations of words in pre-final positions to durations of the same words in final positions. Here's some reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  word1 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
  word2 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
  word3 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
  word4 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
  word5 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
  dur1 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
  dur2 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
  dur3 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
  dur4 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
  dur5 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2))
)
df
# convert words to character:
df[,1:5] <- lapply(df[,1:5], as.character)
```

The pre-final positions in this data include `df[,1:4]`, whereas the final position includes only `df$word5`. Now I also have a set of target words whose durations in either condition I wish to plot in boxplots:

```
targets <- c("A", "C", "E")
```

The question I have difficulty answering is how to plot the durations for the targets in either condition side by side in boxplots. What I've tried so far is this:
I've combined words in pre-final position that are included in `targets`in a single vector:

```
word1to4 <- c(df$word1[df$word1 %in% targets], df$word2[df$word2 %in% targets], df$word3[df$word3 %in% targets],
          df$word4[df$word4 %in% targets])
```

and combined their durations in another single vector:

```
dur1to4 <- c(df$dur1[df$word1 %in% targets], df$dur2[df$word2 %in% targets], df$dur3[df$word3 %in% targets],
         df$dur4[df$word4 %in% targets])
```

and done the same thing for words and durations of words in final position:

```
word5 <- df$word5[df$word5 %in% targets]
dur5 <- df$dur5[df$word5 %in% targets]
```

Now I can plot the durations for pre-final and final words, but unfortunately only in two distinct boxplots:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(dur1to4 ~ word1to4, main="Words 1-4", col="red", frame=F)
boxplot(dur5 ~ word5, main="Word 5", col="blue", frame=F)
```

[image]
I'd much rather have durations for the target words side by side in a single boxplot. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this is to create another vector indicating which grouping the word belongs to and then using the formula expression in the boxplot to properly group the results.  Below, I created one dataframe to hold all of the data and plot from.

```
#Create data frames to hold the data
out<-data.frame(group="word1to4", word=word1to4, duration=dur1to4)
out5<-data.frame(group="word 5", word=word5, duration=dur5)
#Data frame with all of the data
answer<-rbind(out, out5)

#plotting grouping by Word groups and word, add a legend
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
boxplot(answer$duration ~ answer$group +answer$word, main="Words", col=c("red", "blue"), frame=F, las=2)
legend("top",legend=c("Words1-4", "Word5"),  fill=c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you intend on generating a lot of charts in R it may be worth you time to learn to use the ggplot (ggplot2) package. Although there is a bit of a learning curve, it is much more flexible and alows you to create very professional looking graphics.

Here is a solution which uses ggplot.

```
df <- data.frame(
    word1 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
    word2 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
    word3 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
    word4 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
    word5 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
    dur1 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
    dur2 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
    dur3 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
    dur4 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2)),
    dur5 = c(round(abs(rnorm(10)),2))
)
df
# convert words to character:
df[,1:5] <- lapply(df[,1:5], as.character)
targets <- c("A", "C", "E")
word1to4 <- c(df$word1[df$word1 %in% targets], df$word2[df$word2 %in% targets], df$word3[df$word3 %in% targets],
              df$word4[df$word4 %in% targets])
dur1to4 <- c(df$dur1[df$word1 %in% targets], df$dur2[df$word2 %in% targets], df$dur3[df$word3 %in% targets],
             df$dur4[df$word4 %in% targets])

word5 <- df$word5[df$word5 %in% targets]
dur5 <- df$dur5[df$word5 %in% targets]

# Create Dataset to plot
library(ggplot2)

box_data<-data.frame(words=c(word1to4,word5),dur=c(dur1to4,dur5),
                     type=c(rep("1 to 4",length(word1to4)),rep("5",length(word5))))

box_data$type<-as.factor(box_data$type)
box_data$x<-interaction(box_data$words, box_data$type)

box_data$xc<-as.character(box_data$x)
box_data<-box_data[order(box_data$xc),]
box_data
my_boxplot<-ggplot(box_data, aes(x=xc, y=dur)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=type)) +
theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
ggtitle("Duration By Word and Type")

my_boxplot
```

[image]

Comment: The placement is not side by side. How can that be done?

Comment: Just updated my answer to correctly plot the box plots, I did this by changing the interaction term (named "x" in my code) to a character variable (named "xc") and then sorting by "xc" and plotting it on the x-axis